# electron-updater auto update on linux

Tags: linux, electron, quasar, electron-updater

i am desperately in need for help. I have been trying this for so long and i got no results at all.

So, my problem is. I am using the electron-updater package to auto update my electron app. It's working on windows but on linux is another story. I have been looking everywhere and i can't find anything about it.

I am using electron-builder integrated with quasar to package my application, and, i did read about it in the documentations, it's only supported by AppImage formats. Okay that's fair, but what should i even do with that? I am using a custom url-schema and it just doesnt work, it doesn't install it anywhere. It just opens my electron app and that's not the behavior i am expecting.

I have tried using AppImage Launcher but i am getting this silly error (which i dont know why it happens), doesn't provide any description about it and i think i will just give up the project for linux (already did for MacOS) too. I have setup the desktop file, set the executable name, indeed it compiles and it installs perfectly on a .deb package, but i just don't know what to do with this .appimage extension.

My linux configuration on electron-builder looks like this (it will be interpreted by quasar)

```
linux: {
          target: "AppImage",
          executableName: "portscanner",

          desktop: {
            Name: "Port Scanner",
            "Generic Name": "Port Scanner",
            StartupWMClass: "portscanner",
            Terminal: false,
            Type: "Application",
            MimeType: "application/portscanner;x-scheme-handler/portscanner;",
            Categories: "Networking"
          },
          category: "Networking"
        }
```

I will gladly take any help on this. Thank you guys in advance.

**Edit:**
I took note of the error i got on AppImageLauncher and it's the following:
Error registering AppImage in the system via libappimage

And in the terminal i have this error:
ERROR: appimage_register_in_system : Malformed desktop entry: Unexpected token ENTRY_KEY at line 8

But i have no ENTRY_KEY in my desktop config :/

**Edit2:**
I fixed it by removing most of the things of the linux desktop file (except for mimetype) but now i am facing this issue in electron-builder which is the following: **"APPIMAGE env is not defined, current application is not an AppImage"**

I know i have to put the path to the appimage application but which path? The one generated in the dist folder? A path pointing to $HOME? (tried that and didn't work). None of them work btw. I dont know what to do anymore.

Comment: Do you get the same error without asar?

Comment: i updated to the new problem